# Retrieving integers from char buffer/array c

Tags: c

I have a char buffer array `char buffer[1024];`. I know that it has some integers stored in it, lets say for example 4 integers.

Now, I want to extract those values from it and want to save them in few int variables.I have been trying to do it but could not succeed, if some one can please help me in it, I will be really grateful!!!

So far, i have tried to do

```
int firstintfrombuffer = *((int*)(buffer));
```

and

```
int firstintfrombuffer =(int) buffer[0];
```

I am new to c, having trouble with syntax too.
Thank you for any directions to the right way.

Comment: `I know that it has some integers stored in it` you mean the textual representation of integers, or binary integer values?

Comment: hi @fvu thank you for the comment, Actually I am not sure how to answer this but I have four integers, after assigning the values to it, those four are then stored in the buffer. 
And then my method receives this buffer but I am struggling to extract those int values from the buffer array.

Comment: @user3121023 Hi, so my buffer contains {44100,16,1}.Is this what you meant by the content? and thanks for the comment!!!

Comment: @user3121023 I am sorry for confusing you even more, so We are told that you recieve a buffer array with these integers stored in it, I can not see it because I am receiving it from a lets say blackbox. I think if I can use pointer some how, because the first 4 bytes would be first int and then the next 4 would be the second int. Thats what i want to try but I am not sure how because of lack of c skills

Comment: Post the rest of your code. `char buffer[1024]` is for 1024 char's, not integers. If you are putting int into buffer, we need to see what you are doing to really say anything about how to get them out.

Comment: @Nia a char cannot contain 44100.  You will need to explain more precisely how the array was filled (preferably showing code). Otherwise nobody can answer.